# What does this SQL statement mean

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

```
Select
CASE WHEN tr.IsOpenItem <> 0 THEN NCHAR(185) ELSE '' END "Symbol3"
```

**EDIT**

I am unsure what `NCHAR(185)` means. I know how to use case statements but have never really used `NCHAR`. So when it selects `NCHAR(185)` for that row in column `Symbol3`, what will it be its value?

Comment: Have you tried `select NChar(185)`?

Comment: Did you try clicking the `NCHAR(185)` link in my answer?  (But yes, you could have just run `SELECT NCHAR(185)` and gotten your answer)

Comment: Or [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b9/index.htm) snippet from the Unicode standard.

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement over a condition.  If the `IsOpenItem` field is not `0`, it selects [`NCHAR(185)`](http://succulent-plant.com/toys/charwin.html), otherwise it selects an empty string.

`Symbol3` is the name of the column it's for.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically checking your value of tr.IsOpenItem and saying when it's not equal (<>) to 0 then use NCHAR(185).  When it's 0 then you want to use a blank space ('').